# Windows Workflow: How to persist every activity

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have a workflow (Windows Workflow Foundation) that has about 20 activities, imagine if the server goes down when the workflow is executing.
How can i recovery the exactly point that was executing when the server goes down?

Answer (score 1):

Set the workflow to persist on idle and then put a Delay activity before each of your activities.

Comment: This is the only way? i really need to put it before every activity?

Comment: Why would you use Delay before rather than Persist after each activity?

Comment: In this case of every activity being persisted we are looking at persist between.  However,in general if the server goes down in the middle of an activity then persisting before allows the activity to be run again once it is restored.  I like Delay/PersistOnIdle more than a simple Persist as I get to intercept the workflowApplication.PersistableIdle event so I can do some higher level workflow management i.e. remove the workflow from my list of running workflows if an unload flag is set.  Persist if perfectly acceptable if you don't want that.

Comment: @Rafael.  Yes, I believe you add it before every activity.  You can add code to Persist inside an activity but it's a bit of a faff and why bother when the action is available from the toolbox.